# How to Translate this Handwriting into Legible Text

Tags: translation, handwriting

This image is the personnel card of a small-arms factory worker. I am trying to understand his function, department or whatever is written in the third and fourth columns of this image (I cannot read the handwriting or understand abbreviations):

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help you would provide !

Comment: Just a quick note: line 5 uses a different writing script than the other lines, it is more modern. (Compare the h in Werkzeugmacher)

Answer (score 4):

edit: thx to @tofro & @Beta , i added your suggestions for the missing words

It is really hard to read, but let's try

1st line:

> nach Abtlg.: Danhardt (surname?), Lehrling, 3202

2nd line:

> 22.4.41, Werkzeugbau, als: Werkzeugmacher, 35

3rd line:

> 13.1.42, Konstr. Büro, techn. Zeichner, 2373

Konstr. Büro -> Konstruktionsbüro, techn. -> technischer

4th line:

> 14.2.42, Werkzeugbau, Gesenkmacher, 35

[Gesenk](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesenk)

5th line:

> 8.10.45, Werkzeugbau(Ditto mark), Werkzgmacher, 35 (Ditto mark)

Werkzgmacher -> Werkzeugmacher

Comment: 3rd line is rather "Konstr.Büro". Also fits the profession better

Answer (score 3):

To add to the above transscription:

First word could be the surname "Danhardt"

The profession on the fourth line is "Gesenkmacher" a branch of toolmaking

The abbreviation on the end of the second line reads "gel." what i interpret as "gelungen" or maybe "gelobt", i.e he has succeeded in this part of the education.

To summarize:

Mr Danhardt first came to the Tool Making department as an apprentice in July 24th 1941, where he got the first part of an education as a  toolmaker. He remained there until he was approved of, and then went to the Construction Office January 31st 1942 where he was taught technical drawing for about a month until he went back to the tool making department in February 14th and got educated to “Gesenkmacher”, which I believe is an important branch of tool making, where you make the precision made stamps and dies for the large excenter presses where metal parts are formed in industrial manufacturing. He then learnt this complicated and delicate profession for more than 3 ½ years, and then, when completed, worked as a toolmaker from the 8th of October 1945 .

Comment: Really good summary. I also think of "gel." as "gelungen. Maybe within the meaning of "bestanden" or "abgeschlossen".

Comment: Thank you both SO MUCH for your hard work !! Really appreciate your generosity <3